# Dynamic LINQ for RUntime Column Projection

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to implement Dynamic LINQ Query for selected columns to show has Output columns in LINQ Query. 
Here is the error:

> /Property 'System.String CompanyCode' is not defined for type
>   'System.String'"

```
public static void SelectProjection()
{
    DataMovementDataContext dbMovement = new DataMovementDataContext();
    var entity = dbMovement.ListofAccountingDocs2_1075s.AsQueryable();
    Type type = entity.ElementType;
    var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entity.ElementType, "row");
    Expression expr = entityParam;
    string[] props = "AccountingDocumentNbr,CompanyCode,FiscalYearNbr".Split(',');
    foreach (string prop in props)
    {
        // use reflection (not ComponentModel) to mirror LINQ
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
        type = pi.PropertyType;  
    }
    // row => row.Property
    // var columnLambda = Expression.Lambda(  Expression.Property(entityParam, "GLCompanyCode"), entityParam);
    var columnLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(expr, "AccountingDocumentNbr,GLCompanyCode"), entityParam);

    // Items.Select(row => row.Property)
    var selectCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { entity.ElementType, columnLambda.Body.Type }, entity.Expression, columnLambda);

    // Items.Select(row => row.Property).Distinct
    var distinctCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Distinct", new Type[] { typeof(string) }, selectCall);


    // colvalue => colvalue
    var sortParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "AccountingDocumentNbr");
    var columnResultLambda = Expression.Lambda(sortParam, sortParam);

    // Items.Select(row => row.Property).Distinct.OrderBy(colvalue => colvalue)
    var ordercall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy",
                    new Type[] { typeof(string), columnResultLambda.Body.Type },
                    distinctCall, columnResultLambda);

    var result =  entity.Provider.CreateQuery(ordercall);
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```

Can any one provide me help in solving above error?

Comment: What is the variable type at runtime? Before you assign pi.PropertyType.
It seems to me that your loop where you get the property type isnt doing what you want to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

If we look at this code:

```
   // I chnaged this part:

   string[] props = new string[]
   {
        "AccountingDocumentNbr",
        "CompanyCode",
        "FiscalYearNbr"
   };


    Expression expr;
    Type type = entity.ElementType;

    foreach (string prop in props)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);

        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);

        type = pi.PropertyType;   // This line may cause your loop 
                                  // to do something you dont want to do?
    }
```

It seems to me that your loop going down the properties, gets a string and then searches for a prop called CompanyCode, which the class String obviously doesnt have.

Your loop does the following at the moment:

from type get the property named AccountingDocumentNbr

from the return type of property AccountingDocumentNbr get the property called CompanyCode

form the return type of property CompanyCode get the type of the property called FiscalYearNbr

I hardly doubt this is what you really want to do.

Comment: Hi, I want add string column names has projected columns from LINQ Query. Im trying to get the property from the target project. Suppose If I replace type with target object.i.e Type type = entity.ElementType;  Even if I try to comment out type = pi.PropertyType; Still I getting same error.. Please comment out last stmt in for loop and  see if u can get further idea on tht